# Windows Azure: Can I just use it like a standard Windows 2008 Server?

Tags: asp.net, windows, azure, remote-desktop

I've created an Azure server instance. I've deployed a simple application to it.  As part of the deployment process I enabled Remote Desktop Connections.

I have some standard ASP.net applications that run on Windows, is there something to stop me deploying these applications manually to IIS using Remote Desktop.  I've read so much about having to migrate standard ASP.net apps to Azure.  I don't want to this as we will have customers who will still use Windows Server 2003/2008 so I don't want to have to maintain 2 versions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I understand it, in theory you could deploy stuff using remote desktop. But when the instance shuts down/restarts you'll lose it all (unless you've built it into your startup scripts) and have to re-load everything each time. The main reason they suggest you have at least two instances is so that when one shuts down for updates etc there is always at least one other running.
The "[Windows Azure Accelerator for Web Roles](https://github.com/WindowsAzure-Accelerators/wa-accelerator-webroles)" project allows you to create an Azure web role which then enables you to use web deploy for all your other web sites - I'm guessing that will be a whole lot better approach and is definitely worth a look. Also, I believe smarx.com is a good place to browse for info and ideas.

Comment: If my software has dependencies on 3rd party software (Delphi runtime DLL's) that is not part of a web deploy how do I guarantee that this will always be available?

Comment: If they're not part of a deployment then you will have to include them in the main web role package. Alternatively you could create a startup task that downloads, unpacks, sets up all your dependencies. These files could be on a static server somewhere or perhaps in Azure storage.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [startup task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx) and the [Azure Bootstrapper](http://bootstrap.codeplex.com/) you can download, unzip, install almost any kind of 3rd party software that supports either xcopy deployment (just copy the files) or an unattended(silent) install.

Comment: Does this mean that you need to reinstall at every startup or do these tasks only get executed when a new instance is launched?

Comment: a Startup task is executed on each boot. The Windows Azure Bootstrapper however has a clever system that only installs the required software once on a new instance. It simply makes a install log file and checks it when it is executed again.

Comment: Adding to @astaykov's comment: the local disk is considered *non-durable* in that it's not replicated and *could* crash. You can forcibly clear out data on local disks on role recycle, but if not, chances are good that stuff on the disk will stay on the disk. So the trick works pretty well - write some type of breadcrumb on disk that persists across reboots. If the breadcrumb is present, that means your stuff is installed.

Comment: @keitn - The bottom line is: if your software isn't installed when the role instance boots then yes, everything needs to be installed. It's really important that any software to be installed be xcopy-deployable or have an installer with an unattended (automatic) mode. As you scale out to more instances, your new instances go through the same process.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you aren't using Azure storage or anything like that, there shouldn't be any difference with the IIS application.  If you are using anything specific to Azure, you can use the `RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable` to test if you are running inside Azure or not.  That will return true for the emulator as well.  If you want to use Azure storage from both, you can add the settings in the web.config to use if not running in Azure.